# Batch: Storing string variables?

Tags: variables, batch-file

I'm coding an RPG and and when I set a variable that I want to be a name,

when I `"echo My name is %name%"`, which I stored the name in,

it shows as `"My name is 0"`.

However, when I code a smaller program, it works. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You clearly set `name` to 0 at some point. If the variable was unset, you would see the message `My name is %name%`.

Comment: Put a `setlocal` command at beginning of _all_ your programs!

Answer (score 2):

(For some funny reason i can't comment)

You may have used the `/a` parameter while setting the variable previously. That would mean that the variable would be treated as if it was holding a number. This `set /a name=Name` should be `set name=Name`.

Also, as dbenham mentioned, `set /a name=Name` evaluates to 0, explaining your problem.

Comment: No need to comment, this is a good answer. Also,  `set /a name=SomeName` evaluates to 0 if there does not exist a variable named SomeName. This would explain the source of the 0 value.